# How can I make GetKeyState understand the capital and noncapital letters

Tags: c, winforms, case-sensitive

Hey guys I'm using Codeblocks from C. I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx but I can't understand what I need to change in this code to make it case-sensitive.

```
void getInput()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if((GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8008)) {
            printf("qwe");
        }
    }
}
```

Code works and I don't get any errors. Only problem is this doesn't differentiate between pressing `a` or `A`, it will print `qwe` in both cases. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the problem? You want to print it `qwe` or you don't want it to print it?

Comment: when i print A , i want it to print qwe.but when i press 'a' , i dont want it to print qwe.

Comment: You should check the state of `shift` key as well then. Perhaps `Caps lock` too.

Comment: So caps lock being on or off won't make a difference and i need to make another check on if VK_SHIFT is being pushed?

Comment: 'a' and 'A' are the same key... unless your keyboard has separate keys for 'a' and 'A'?

Comment: @BerkayMenevşe you should post the solution you've found as a self-answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: Hmm sorry it was my first question so i dont know what you mean by post the solution.if you explain how to do it to me i will do it next time

Comment: A question is a question. Post the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @EugeneSh., solution is to check the state of `VK_CAPITAL`, see if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is on:

```
if((GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x41) && GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)) {
    key_pressed=KEY_A; printf("qwe");
}
if((GetAsyncKeyState('B') & 0x8008) && !GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)) {
    key_pressed=KEY_B; printf("asd");
}
```